# C# Importing CSV string as well as Integer data type using OleDb

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I am importing a csv file using oledb. For integer and string datatype.

My code is

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), fileName);
    excelConnectionString = string.Format(
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited""",
                Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
                );
                string qry = "SELECT * FROM " + fileName ;
                OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry, excelConnectionString);
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                myCommand.Fill(dTable);
```

And my Csv file is

```
Abc,Price ----> Header
123,$1.80
456,$7.19
789,$7.19
156,$23.69
G123,$13.52
G456,$98.62
G789,$210.00
G159,$270.00
G753,$390.00
G852,$61.79
G145,$11.66
```

Now my problem is first 4 lines it is uploading and the remaining lines are uploading as null. I am not getting any exceptions also. Please help me for this.

Comment: First you must set HDR=YES

Comment: I set HDR=YES. But still same problem

Comment: First four rows after this show null? First column?

Comment: After first four rows it is showing null. First four rows uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It`s because first column contains string and integer values.

You must create "schema.ini" which must to be located in the same folder as the *.csv file with next structure

```
[yourName.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1=Abc Text
Col2=Price Text
```

Comment: can you send your schema.ini file?

Comment: [hi.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
Col2=B Text 
Col3=C Text

Comment: Why you use "B" and "C" for name columns? At your case it`s Abc and Price

Comment: Your file located at hi.csv folder?

Comment: sorry. My file is like [hi.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1=Abc Text
Col2=Price Text